# To view the database field data in the admin page custom module

Tags: forms

How to show the data from the database in the admin page of custom module. The listed data should be edited/deleted/view.

Please say what Hook is to be used in the.inc file

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to get your fields in a page. 
You can try

[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) OR [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data)

If you prefer some coding you could try [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) or [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7)

I would do it by `theme_table` if i prefer coding.

> Returns HTML for a table.

Read [HowTo: Create Simple Tables](http://drupal.org/node/156863)

```
<?php
  $header = array('Node ID', 'Title', 'Type', 'Terms', 'Created', 'Published', 'Sticky', 'Promoted');
  $rows = array();
  $no_yes = array('No', 'Yes');

  $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} ORDER BY promote DESC, sticky DESC, created DESC");

  while ($node = db_fetch_object($results)) {
    $termlist = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node->nid);
    $terms = array();
    foreach ($termlist as $key => $value) { $terms[] = $value->name; }
    $rows[] = array($node->nid,
                    l($node->title, 'node/'. $node->nid .'/edit'),
                    $node->type,
                    implode(' | ', $terms),
                    format_date($node->created),
                    $no_yes[$node->status],
                    $no_yes[$node->sticky],
                    $no_yes[$node->promote],
                );
   }
  return theme('table', $header, $rows);
?>
```

**To get Edit/Delete work you should write your own code if its not nodes.**

Comment: The records are not showing in the overlay of the admin custom module. kindly help me out

Comment: is it under the overlay ?

Comment: above the overlay

Comment: @sindhu, if my answer helped you consider up-vote the answer.